# Random numbers in web page url

Tags: web

I want to create static URL for my website pages and looking for some good methods.

I check multiple websites and found there many web pages URL has some random number at end.

Example-

> randomweb.com/how-to-feed-a-baby-90kfdsio

What is its purpose of last random  number when

> randomweb.com/how-to-feed-a-baby

can be a valid URL.

Can any one suggest some good way to give unique URL to webpages which can take care of same url path.

Comment: The reason for the random id at the end is that you'll have unique URLs even when the titles are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Many content management systems or blog software can handle this situation. For example, Wordpress allows for unique URLs that can be whatever you want them to be per page. It will really just depend on the software you are using for your website.